# How do I let my Client edit my webpage?

Tags: web, html, edit

So, I have a client who needs a website. Although he would like to edit the webpage when I put it into the web. So I am wondering how would it be possible for **just** my client to edit the website, and not any other users. In HTML, CSS, JS of course!

Thanks, Albert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How competent is you client? Here's a few way I can see someone who is decently competent at computers editing a website (I've used them all):

1. SSH: If the site is running on a server with SSH, your client can directly SSH into the server and edit files. Not highly recommended but this is the "easiest" way (May be able to use their text editor via an SFTP plugin too to edit files on the server).
2. Git: Attach the web root to a git repository. This way the client can edit whatever they want on a local copy on their machine, test it and then deploy it to production or test by SSHing into the server and updating the repo.
3. No SSH? Use FTP is download the files, edit them on local machine and then upload new version to server.

All these options assumes the client can use the tools needed (SSH, Git or FTP) and knows webdev.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, that was my backup plan.. (what you just posted)

Answer (score 0):

consider using some CMS, like WordPress or Drupal, so your client can edit almost anything on website without digging into git-flow or other technologies. I guess if he knew how to do it, he wouldn't ask. Another option is to create web site on a platform like Wix (or similar), but in this case customisation will be limited by platform